# Tokenizer and Nietzsche

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm playing with tf and text generation task. I was able successfully to master classical Nietzsche example. Now I'm trying it with using Tokenizer. Things looked good, I was able to start fitting process, and even it converged , but I ended up in following result:

```
Epoch 1/60
200256/200281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.1613 - acc: 0.3707
Input: a
Output:
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Please look at my notebook. I've been fighting with this issue for a few days. Thanks in advance

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uUZ-hZAnJBU8o841K6T51gnKfEbCB3JX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue. It seems it was in `predict` function.

```
seq = token.texts_to_sequences(text)
```

needs to change to

```
seq = token.texts_to_sequences([text])
```

Since text_to_sequence expects array as parameter